# Harmonic number symbol

Tags: fonts, symbols, amssymb

The harmonic series symbol is often denoted by H in LaTeX, that looks like this:
[image]

On Knuth's Concrete Mathematics book, the symbol looks like this:

[image]

The book used `AMS Euler` as the typesetting font, where the normal "H" and the harmonic "H" were different. Is there any dedicated symbol for the harmonic series in LaTeX?

Comment: You want all math symbol use euler or just specific symbol.

Comment: The harmonic H is the normal H in math mode

Comment: It's not *the* symbol for the harmonic numbers. It's just an H in the math font that's used in “Concrete Mathematics”, nothing special at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not just the `H`. The subscript `k` is also in Euler math. You can use `\mathit{H}` with Euler math to get something close to a CM math $H$:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{euler}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

Math H and italic H: $H_k\mathit{H}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unlike @Sandy's excellent response I have used `eulervm` package to write the notation that you desired.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\begin{document}
\[\sum^{k}_{1}{\frac 1k}=H_k\]
\end{document}
```

[image]